# Books on RPG IV for a Ruby programmer?

Tags: ruby, rpg

I'm a Ruby programmer and need to learn RPG IV because of my current project. I want to learn primitive types, data structures, control flows, architecture etc. Online resources are as good as paper books.

What book or online tutorial should I start with?

Comment: What specifically do you need to learn? There are a TON of resources online where you don't really need to invest in a book.

Comment: I'm not sure. But, I guess I want to learn primitive types, data structures, control flows, architecture etc. Online resources is as good as paper books. I'll edit the question.

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745106/i-want-to-learn-rpg-iv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [Red Book from IBM](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg245402.html) is still quite relevant today.

[IBM i Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzahg/rzahgrpgcode.htm) is the source for the actual documentation.

[RPG-L](http://murl.me/rpgl) is a great mailing list with hundreds of helpful people to answer all of your questions.

Another link I knew was out there, but couldn't find at first was from [Scott Klement](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/howtolearn.html) who is well known in the IBM i community.

Answer (score 2):

You can run [JRuby](http://www.jruby.org/) natively on the iSeries if that's your primary skill set.

There may be some pushback if you have some stodgy graybeards that are afraid of new technology stacks.